# How to transform the co-ordinates of the corner of an image from one screen size to another?

Tags: android

Basically i want to recognize alphabets on any android phone when i swiped on an image of an alphabet.. In order to do this i found out the co ordinates of the corners and some middle points and some other ones on the alphabet on one phone using log cat.when someone swipes their hand over the alphabet the phone detects if he went through those basic points at least and then recognizes if he traced the alphabet or not. This recognition technique obviously wont work on other phones.The question is how to make them work on other devices of different screen sizes? Moreover just using "dpi" wont work, i tried this but i think that one will have to adjust for the varying width and height among phones not just the density.

Answer (score 0):

Use normalized coordinates for storage and processing - top left is (0.0, 0.0) and bottom right is (1.0, 1.0). You can convert between screen coordinates and normalized coordinates by simply dividing/multiplying with the screen resolution.

Screen to normalized:

```
double nx = ((double) x) / screenWidth;
double ny = ((double) y) / screenHeight;
```

Normalized to screen:

```
int x = (int) (nx * screenWidth);
int y = (int) (ny * screenHeight);
```